# Is it possible to add a child post into the parent page?

Tags: page-template, pages, template-tags

Is it possible to add a child post into the parent page?
Basically I have a 1 parent page and it has 2 child page that has a simple content , and I want the child page content to put also in the parent page ,BUT making it an as a excerpt, not output all content (just a teaser).

Havent clue yet how to pull that..

any help will do

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to query the child Pages:

```
$pageargs = array(
  'numberposts' => -1,
  'orderby' => 'menu_order',
  'order' => 'ASC',
  'post_type' => 'page',
  'post_parent' => $post->ID
);
$childpages = get_posts( $pageargs );
```

Then, you need to create your custom Loop:

```
foreach ( $childpages as $childpage ) {
    // Output whatever you want here, such as:
    ?>
    <h2><?php echo $childpage->post_title; ?></h2>
    <?php echo $childpage->post_exerpt; ?>
<?php }
```

Note, however, that Pages do not by default support excerpts. So, you'll need to enable that, in `functions.php`:

```
// Add Excerpt to Pages
add_post_type_support( 'page', 'excerpt' );
```

Then, you should be all set.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`get_page()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page) in [template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Page_Templates) of your parent page and retrieve child page. Then access data form it and format/output it.